# SQL on BigQuery: Consolidate pivot column when using a double selection with full join

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Given the following query:

```
SELECT TAB_1.*, TAB_2.* EXCEPT(date), TAB_2.date AS tab_2_date FROM
  (
    SELECT
      date,
      grob as `grob_r1`
    FROM `mytab_tbl`
    WHERE region = "r1"
  )
  AS TAB_1 FULL JOIN 
  (
    SELECT
      date,
      grob as `grob_r2`
    FROM `mytab_tbl`
    WHERE region = "r2"
  )
  AS TAB_2
ON TAB_1.date = TAB_2.date
```

I get this result:

```
Row   | date         | grob_r1  | grob_r2   | tab_2_date    
=========================================================
1     | null         | null     | 10        | 2020-03-28
2     | 2020-03-29   | 20       | null      | null
```

The problem I see is that I don't get the col date populated by the second selection. I would like to get rid of `tab_2_date` and consolidate a unique `date` column, basically acting as a pivot.

Desired output:

```
Row   | date         | grob_r1  | grob_r2   
==========================================
1     | 2020-03-28   | null     | 10
2     | 2020-03-29   | 20       | null
```

Note: I cannot use directly the same `date` within my query because BigQuery does not support duplicate column names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH aux AS (
    SELECT date, region, grob FROM `mytab_tbl` WHERE region IN ('r1', 'r2')
)

SELECT 
    date
    , MAX(IF(region = 'r1', grob, NULL)) AS grob_r1
    , MAX(IF(region = 'r2', grob, NULL)) AS grob_r2

FROM aux 

GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot (again). Just a clarification: why do I need to use the `MAX` statement?

Comment: Just so the values are grouped by date and you don't get duplicated dates.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query for your problem

Working example with sample data:

```
WITH
rawdata AS
(
  SELECT CAST('2020-03-28' as date) AS date, 'r2' as region, 10 as grob union all
  SELECT CAST('2020-03-29' as date) AS date, 'r1' as region, 20 as grob
)
select date, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN region = 'r1' THEN grob END) as grob_r1, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN region = 'r2' THEN grob END) as grob_r2
from rawdata
group by date
```

You should use:

```
select date, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN region = 'r1' THEN grob END) as grob_r1, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN region = 'r2' THEN grob END) as grob_r2
from `mytab_tbl`
group by date
```

Comment: Is this working on static data? I need a query able to work on parameters, not values. Generally I don't know the latter in advance.

Comment: This solution is good, but probably took the problem too literally. I am making some edits to account for that. 
I don't think the MAX are necessary at all, and an IF is easier to read here.
edit; Actually, changed my mind, the solution is very different, I would be rewriting the whole thing. 

Just to note, this person gave you this query as it does literally what your example needs, so you could use it as a guide for sure.

Comment: What do you mean by parameters?
I'm editing it now, to show how should you use it.

Comment: Just went ahead an re-wrote it on a separate answer. Probably that's what OP wanted but feel free to edit your and I will delete mine.

Comment: No worries, you can keep it :) That's using IF instead of CASE, so a different approach.